# Finding friends in a svd decomposition

Tags: svd

I'm trying to implement collaborative filtering Recommender system using svd. I have all the matrices `Uk`,`Sk`,`Vkt`. And have also rating matrix.

```
Uk
−0.4312452 0.4931501
−0.5327375 −0.5305257
−0.5237456 −0.4052007
−0.5058743 0.5578152

sqrt.Sk
12.2215 0
0 4.9282

Vkt
−0.3593326 0.36767659
−0.5675075 0.08799758
−0.4428526 0.56862492
−0.5938829 −0.73057242
```

Also I have the `user A vector: {5, 3, 4, 4}` and `user B: {2, 5, 1, 3}`

I need help on finding the similarity between users A and B.